# Two SQL queries into one query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to join two SQL queries, ive tried some solutions to previously asked questions on stack, and cant get the desired output.

my first SQL query is

```
SELECT * FROM albums_songs 
LEFT JOIN audio USING(AUDID) 
WHERE ARTID='".mysql_real_escape_string($artid)."' 
AND ALBID='".mysql_real_escape_string($albid)."'
```

the second is

```
SELECT * FROM `albums_s` 
WHERE ALBUMID='".mysql_real_escape_string($albid)."' 
AND placeholder='1'
```

I need these to join into a single table after the SQL query that joins them, and have it ordered by `ORDER BY sorder asc`

the best query that i have tried is the following, except it multiplies the two queries together as a matrix multiplication and the result is additional rows.:

```
 SELECT * FROM 

(SELECT * FROM albums_s 
    LEFT JOIN audio USING(AUDID)) as t1, 

(SELECT * FROM `albums_s`) as t2 

WHERE t1.ARTID='".mysql_real_escape_string($artid)."' 
AND t1.ALBID='".mysql_real_escape_string($albid)."'  
AND t2.placeholder='1' 
AND t2.ALBID='".mysql_real_escape_string($albid)."' 
ORDER BY t1.sorder asc";
```

So the result should be the identical results to the first two queries, but just joined into a final array and ordered by `sorder asc`

edit/
output of query 1 is large, but the necessary items are: and some example data

```
AUDID    ASID    ALBID    ARTID    sorder    placeholder    sname     phname    phimage   coverart    playcount
  2        1       4        72        5           0          name1         NULL        NULL       img1.jpg    543
  5        2       4        72        2           0          name2         NULL        NULL      img2.jpg    127
  4        3       6        72        3           0          name3         NULL        NULL      img3.jpg
```

output of query 2

```
AUDID    ASID    ALBID    ARTID    sorder    placeholder    phname    phimage
  6       4        4        72        4           1           name4     img4.jpg
```

After the new query, the result  should be (WHERE ALBID=4 and ARTID=72)

```
AUDID    ASID    ALBID    ARTID    sorder    placeholder    sname  phname    phimage   coverart    playcount
  5        2       4        72        2           0         name2         NULL        NULL      img2.jpg    127 
  4        3       6        72        3           0         name3         NULL        NULL      img3.jpg
  6       4        4        72        4           1         NULL          name4     img4.jpg    NULL    NULL
  2        1       4        72        5           0         name1         NULL        NULL       img1.jpg    543
```

as can be seen, the outputs are identical, the only difference is the tables have been joined into one, and then ordered by sorder

Comment: Show result of query 1, query 2 and your join query.

Comment: if i knew how to simply do it like your saying, dont you think i already would have? ;)

Comment: I guess bos mean to post the result of the queries so we can better help you

Comment: Show **us** the result of query 1, query 2 and your join query... If you don't know how to do that, then you're in a tough chair.

Comment: sorry i misread your response, thought it was an answer on how to do it, not a question on what you wanted to see, added in the edit above

Comment: In addition to results, show some sample of the raw data you are querying against and what you would LIKE to have as output.

Comment: okay, added some raw data, and what the output table should look like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select t.sorder, t.other_fields from (query1 union query2) t order by t.sorder asc